# main window getting focus when opening dialog in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using python3 on windows and when I'm pressing the 'open_dialog_button' a dialog is indeed opening (and above all windows and that's good) but the main window is jumping in front of the new window, how do I prevent from the main window to get focus when I'm pressing the dialog button?
I want the main window to be in the back then the new window the the dialog window, I've tries lift() but its working just before and after the dialog window not in the process of the dialog button, I also tried attributes('-topmost', True) but then the new window is above the dialog window as well and I don't want that..
here is just a code example of my specific problem:

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("main window")
        self.geometry('100x100')
        self.new_window_button = ttk.Button(self, text="open new window", command=self.open_new_window)
        self.new_window_button.pack()

    def open_new_window(self):
        NewWindow(self)


class NewWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("new window")
        self.geometry('100x100')
        path = ""
        self.open_dialog_button = ttk.Button(self, text='open dialog', command=self.open_dialog)
        self.open_dialog_button.pack()

    def open_dialog(self):
        global path
        path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/c", title="Choose File")


def main():
    run = MainWindow()
    run.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because the dialog default set parent to main window.
You just need add parent to the second window.

```
path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/c", title="Choose File", parent=self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.grab_set()`

```
def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
    self.title("new window")
    self.geometry('100x100')

    self.focus_force()
    self.grab_set()
```